How do I use EXPLAIN to identify next step in query optimization?
I've got a database query which performs somewhat sluggish in production. The database is a managed AWS MySQL RDS instance.
It is not uncommon for this query to take 5 - 10 seconds.

I know that char(36) is not the most optimal choice of primary key.
The keywordnode_track table has about 50.000.000 rows.
The keywordnode table has about 2000 rows.

Doing a visual explain in MySQL Workbench shows the following :


When I execute the query in MySQL Workbench, I see that fetch time usually is much higher than query time. The query time is usually reported to a few hundred miliseconds (which I consider fine). However, the fetch stage is usually reported in seconds.

Using set profiling=1, I see the following :
'starting', '0.002122'
'checking permissions', '0.000016'
'checking permissions', '0.000006'
'Opening tables', '0.001670'
'init', '0.000016'
'System lock', '0.000011'
'optimizing', '0.000276'
'statistics', '0.020936'
'preparing', '0.000265'
'executing', '29.341943'
'end', '0.000029'
'query end', '0.000006'
'waiting for handler commit', '0.000015'
'closing tables', '0.000014'
'freeing items', '0.000387'
'cleaning up', '0.000026'

I find it hard to interpret the cost, and how the cost affects the timing of the query. Based on the explain of the query, what steps should I do next to identify why the query is slow?
The query :
SELECT
    this_.id AS id1_21_1_,
    this_.updated AS updated2_21_1_,
    this_.track_id AS track3_21_1_,
    this_.keywordnode_id AS keywordn4_21_1_,
    this_.status AS status5_21_1_,
    kwd1_.id AS id1_19_0_,
    kwd1_.updated AS updated2_19_0_,
    kwd1_.name AS name3_19_0_,
    kwd1_.selectable AS selectab4_19_0_,
    kwd1_.parentid AS parentid5_19_0_
FROM
    keywordnode_track this_
INNER JOIN keywordnode kwd1_ ON
    this_.keywordnode_id = kwd1_.id
WHERE
    this_.track_id in ([...],[...],[...],...)

The database tables involved :
CREATE TABLE `keywordnode_track` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `sid` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keywordnode_id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `track_id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FK_keywordnode_track_keywordnode` (`keywordnode_id`,`track_id`),
  KEY `FK_keywordnode_track_track` (`track_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_keywordnode_track_keywordnode` FOREIGN KEY (`keywordnode_id`) REFERENCES `keywordnode` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_keywordnode_track_track` FOREIGN KEY (`track_id`) REFERENCES `track` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE `keywordnode` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `parentid` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `selectable` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_keywordnode_keywordnode` (`parentid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_keywordnode_keywordnode` FOREIGN KEY (`parentid`) REFERENCES `keywordnode` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;


This plan actually doesn't explain why the query is taking so long, 30K rows is almost nothing for modern RDBMS. What you should do - is to look where exactly these 5-10 seconds are spent; use mysql profiling.
Something like
set profiling=1;
--- actually send your query
select [...];
show profiles;
show profile for query <query with select>;


As usual, Profiling provides nothing useful.

How much RAM do you have?  If it under 8GB, that query will be I/O-bound, hence slow.
Yes, UUIDs are slow.  And big.  Instead of trying to replace them with INTs, let's at least try to use BINARY(16), which will cut the table sizes roughly in half.  What version of MySQL are you using?  See what function exists on that version for turning CHAR(36) into BINARY(16).  (Or see: UUIDs .)
This index may help:
this_:  INDEX(track_id, keywordnode_id,  id, updated, status)

When adding that, also drop FK_keywordnode_track_track.

The database had 32GB RAM, so should be plenty. As the BINARY(16) is not a "drop in replacement" for CHAR(36) I will have to do a migration anyway to using that key - so wouldn't it be better to just go for INT in the first place then?

@sbrattla - INT AUTO_INCREMENT would be better unless the ids need to be generated independently by various clients -- in which case some form of UUID is probably necessary.

I added some more.
